# How can i have different values at view and in model in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have read all possible solutions and nothing has helped me yet.

I want a date format on view of type **dd-mm-yy** and at model i want it to be **yyyy-mm-dd**.

Please suggest me a better way to achieve it.

I have tried **ControlValueAccessor** but couldn't implement it.

**A plunker of same would be really helpfull.**

***Thank You in Advance...***

Comment: Use the [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: I'll be using a 3rd party date widget so date pipe might not work, any other way to display different model and view values you know?

Comment: What does your date widget return? A string? Whatever the case, you can create a [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) to transform the date you're getting to the format you want.

Comment: When I will be submitting the form when using date pipe will the format defined in the date pipe going to be the value passed in ngModel?

Comment: @RachitBhatnagar No, pipe filter is just to display the value. It does not modify your ngModel variable. Check this simple code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anq1gs?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using date pipe of angular.

In the below code `todayDate` can be of type `dd-mm-yy`. Pipe will convert it to required format.

```
<input type="text"
       [value]="todayDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'" />
```

Comment: I will be using a 3rd party date widget so this solution is not possible ,I need to do it with controlvalueaccessor.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried? Without code its hard to understand your question.